# Is it advisable or okay to view heatmap of categorical features?

Tags: correlation

As the title suggested. By default sns.heatmap will not include categorical features which are not factorized.

Since factorized categorical features do not behave like a scale (eg. Quality: 0-10), I assume we can't it's not advisable on categorical features?

Is there any other good practice that we can use to detect strong correlation between the categorical features (among themselves and with the label)?

Comment: You are better off with lmplots to detect the trend in the dataset

Comment: Try with encoding first using LabelEncoder then apply heatmap. Hope it should help.

Comment: @manoharamrutkar the downside of this will be too many features in the heatmap huh?

Comment: You can try Target Encoding

Answer (score 1):

It tends on the type of categorical variables: ordinal or nominal.

If the variables are ordinal, then [Spearman's Rank-Order correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) can be calculated. Those values can be visualized with a heatmap.

If the variables are nominal, a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table) can be created. If the cells contain odds ratio, then a useful heatmap can be created.

Comment: Are there any wrapper based techniques for feature selection of categorical variables? Or filter based techniques are the only way to go?